# In VS2010 which functions are exported into a DLL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, dllexport

I am building a DLL to wrap a C/C++ library to be called from matlab.

I am using the standard `__declspec(dllexport)` to export functions.  Specifically, I have several .h files with code that essentially looks like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef _MSC_VER
__declspec(dllexport)
#endif
void FOO();

#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

Then, I have a `lib.h` file, that just includes all these `.h` files.

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
```

My project configuration is such that it does build a DLL, but the mystery is that `BAR()` is in the DLL (as verified by `dumpbin`) but `FOO` is not.

Any ideas on how this could possibly be the case?

Comment: Accuracy is *very* important with a question like this.  So posting code that cannot possibly compile doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example above, the problem was due to the fact that BAR did not have a definition in the source tree of the project.

I'm relatively new to TFS and VS, so let me see if I can explain this in a way that makes sense.

The solution has multiple projects.  One project is called `MatlabDLL`, the main project is called `OurLibrary`.  The Matlab DLL is not importing all of Library, just wraps parts of it for inclusion into Matlab.  In many cases, Matlab DLL can easily call directly to the C functions, in other cases, functions have to be rewritten to handle Matlab C/DLL calling semantics.

So, `BAR` had to have a Matlab specific C wrapper around it to enable it to be called from Matlab.  The associated source file bar.cpp was in the MatlabDLL project.  (Under the hood, `BAR` calls a number of functions whose source lives in the `OurLibrary` project, none of whose source files are in the MatlabDLL project.)

`FOO` had an implementation that did not require a C specific wrapper, so foo.cpp lived in the `OurLibrary` part of the source tree, and had no source files in the `MatlabDLL` project, although it's associated `.h` file was referenced by `MatlabDLL.h`.

In the end, VS2010 appears to only build the `__declspec(dllexport)`'d functions that have associated `c` files in the project.  Adding `foo.c` to the project fixed the problem.